# How to set color for string in android

Tags: android, string, textview

I am having a `webview`. I am just retrieving the `webview's` content in a `string` and displaying it in `textview`. In `onTouch` event the text will read aloud. Now i want to highlight the text word by word in `onTouch` event which the text is speaking. For `textview` we can use `setTextColor`. But how to `setTextColor` for string?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SpannableString`, for example:

```
final String s = editText.getText().toString();
final Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(s);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Update the `endIndex` to point to the end of whatever word is being spoken,

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this too

```
String name = "Test String"; 
textView.setText( Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font color=\"#%s\">text</font>", name ), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE));
```